# Python encoding turns "ã" into "Ã£"

Tags: python, encoding

I send data to my Python server through a WebSocket. There is just one problem. When I send something like:

`ãèêüß`

Python turns it into this:

`Ã£Ã¨ÃªÃ¼Ã\x9f`

How can I format it back to readable style?

Thank you!

Comment: latin-1 encoding should handle this.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre thank you for your comment. I am relatively new to Python, how can I do this?

Comment: something like `result.encode("latin-1")`, or `decode`, I always mix those up...

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Lol, you confused me

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre this results in `b'\xc3\xa3\xc3\xa8\xc3\xaa\xc3\xbc\xc3\x9f'`, which printed is the same unreadable mess.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ when I don't have the code, I always mix those up. So  I would try one , then the other (like when plugging an USB key into a port :))

Comment: ok, that will be ` b'\xc3\xa3\xc3\xa8\xc3\xaa\xc3\xbc\xc3\x9f'.decode("utf-8")` => `ãèêüß`

Comment: can you show us the relevant part of your code? without a context it's difficult to answer clearly

Comment: Thank you all very much!

Comment: the question is multifaceted: what is your server actually *sending* and what are you receiving and how are you printing it. Please provide a [mcve]. Oh and your python version is kind of relevant too!

Comment: And latin1 encoding is **very much wrong** @Jean-FrançoisFabre

Comment: @AnttiHaapala first thing that came to my mind. utf-8 is the right choice, yes.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try:

```
weirdstr.encode("latin-1").decode("utf-8")
```

Works for me.

Comment: encoding in latin 1 then decoding in utf 8 doesn't make a lot of sense. Plus your snippet has 2 "dots".

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre I tested this. I had to first encoding into latin-1 before decoding to utf-8 in order for this to work. Without latin-1 encoding it didn't work.